# Cant resolve requirements to install set of packages in Zend 2 Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have cloned my fork of Zend 2 from github because i wanted to do some tests after i found potential bug, problem is that i cant run tests because Bootstrap cant find autoload.php in vendor folder. I figured out that i need to run composer to update my vendor with packeges just like in other Zend 2 apps. Composer.phar is up-to-date.

Problem is that when i run php composer.phar install on this composer.json:

```
{
"name": "zendframework/zendframework",
"description": "Zend Framework 2",
"type": "library",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/annotations": ">=1.0",
    "ircmaxell/random-lib": "dev-master",
    "ircmaxell/security-lib": "dev-master",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "0.4.*",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "*@dev",
    "phpunit/PHPUnit": "3.7.*"
},
"suggest": {
    "ext-intl": "ext/intl for i18n features (included in default builds of PHP)",
    "doctrine/annotations": "Doctrine Annotations >=1.0 for annotation features",
    "ircmaxell/random-lib": "Fallback random byte generator for Zend\\Math\\Rand if OpenSSL/Mcrypt extensions are unavailable",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "ProxyManager to handle lazy initialization of services",
    "zendframework/zendpdf": "ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes",
    "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "ZendService\\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\\Captcha and/or Zend\\Form"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Zend\\": "library/"
    }
},
"bin": [
    "bin/classmap_generator.php",
    "bin/pluginmap_generator.php",
    "bin/templatemap_generator.php"
],
"replace": {
    "zendframework/zend-authentication": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-barcode": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-cache": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-captcha": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-code": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-config": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-console": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-crypt": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-db": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-debug": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-di": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-dom": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-escaper": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-feed": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-file": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-filter": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-form": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-http": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-i18n": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-inputfilter": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-json": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-ldap": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-loader": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-log": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-mail": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-math": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-memory": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-mime": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-navigation": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-paginator": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-permissions-acl": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-permissions-rbac": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-progressbar": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-resources": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-serializer": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-server": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-session": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-soap": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-tag": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-test": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-text": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-uri": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-version": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-view": "self.version",
    "zendframework/zend-xmlrpc": "self.version"
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev",
        "dev-develop": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
```

}

I got this error message:

Installing dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[1.0.0].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.5, 1.0.0].
- Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 2.2.5 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.2.5].

I tried different approaches, giving different zendframework versions but I got similar error.
Can someone explain to me what i`m missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed that composer.json yourself, and it differs in a very important point: Your version states that THIS software is called "zendframework/zendframework" (the version number is derived from the tag of your version control), and you explicitly state that you need "zendframework/zendframework" version 2.2.5.

This package cannot be zendframework/zendframework "your version" and "2.2.5" at the same time.

You cannot require the software you are representing yourself. You should probably explain in some more detail what you are trying to do, but as a starter: If you clone the original ZF2 repo, fix a bug there by committing to your clone (in some appropriate branch), and then want to test if that bug is fixed in some other software that requires zendframework/zendframework, you simply include YOUR repository in that software's composer.json and require something like "2.2.x@dev". Updating should check out the latest commit of YOUR ZF2 clone.

Comment: Yeah i know it might be bad shot, as you pointed that out. I will do what you said and tell if it works. I did create commit and send it as appropriate branch and its in issue list now i have to do tests for that. Thing is i dont know how to send tests to them and in what environment i should do them. I though i should make them also in Zend 2 library clone but you said i should do it in one of my applications if i understands you correctly.

Comment: I did what you wrote and it worked but still i dont know how to run test for Zend 2 library which i should do now. I coundt find any tutorial about running tests for libraries how to structure that only for modules.